# Optional's `orElse` lazy evaluation fail leads to performance hit

Tags: java, option-type

Consider the following use case of an application with a user preference system:

We want to get the bool value of the preference `MyFlag`.
In the best case we want it from the settings of the current user.
If that fails, we want to get `MyFlag` from the default settings.
If even that fails, throw.

The settings are on a server. This connection is slow and can fail.
Fetching the settings and getting the prefernce can all fail, too.
So lets use javas Optionals:

```
public static boolean getMyFlag()throws NoSuchElementException
{
        return getUserOrDefaultPreference("MY_FLAG");
}

private Boolean getUserOrDefaultPreference(String preferenceName) throws NoSuchElementException
{
    return Optional.ofNullable(getConnection())              // get slow connection
        .map(connection -> connection.getUserSettings())     // get user settings
        .map(settings -> settings.getPref(preferenceName))   // return preference
        .orElse(slowlyGetDefaultPreference(preferenceName)); // or else return default value
}

private Boolean slowlyGetDefaultPreference(String preferenceName) throws NoSuchElementException
{
    return Optional.ofNullable(getConnection())             // get slow connection
        .map(connection -> connection.getDefaultSettings()) // get default settings
        .map(settings -> settings.getPref(preferenceName))  // return preference
        .orElseThrow(() ->  new NoSuchElementException());  // if any of the above fails throw
}
```

Problem here is that the connection can be very slow. When `.orElse(slowlyGet...);` is called the func `slowlyGetDefaultPreference()` is evaluated first, regardless, if my optional is empty or has a value. This is a performance penalty, I have to avoid.

I tried using a supplier via `.orElseGet(() -> slowlytGet..)`, but that resulted in the same problem.

So my only recourse is the ugly `isPresent()` anti-pattern, which from a readability standpoint ruins the whole Optional flow:

```
private Boolean getUserOrDefaultPreference(String preferenceName) throws NoSuchElementException
{
    Optional<Boolean> opt = Optional.ofNullable(getConnection())
        .map(connection -> connection.getUserSettings())  
        .map(settings -> settings.getPref(preferenceName));

    if(opt.isPresent())
    {
        return opt.get();
    }
    else
    {
        slowlyGetDefaultPreference(preferenceName));
    }
}
```

The same holds for throwing the exception, as I do not want to pay the cost of constructing one.

Am I missing something here or is this the only solution?

Comment: `orElseGet` should work exactly the same as the last example, I don't understand why you say it has the same issue as `orElse`

Comment: @Magnus I steped through the code with the debugger and could see, that for `orElse` `getSlow..()` was invoked.

Comment: Yes, because evaluation from `orElseGet` is only called, when some function before `orElseGet` has null object. But if You use `orElse` is called always

Comment: @DaFrenk the code for Optional.orElseGet is very simple and it should not do that unless the Optional was null. See my answer for an example.

Comment: @DaFrenk I think you missread my comment, I was talking about `orElseGet` working like your last example, not `orElse`, of course you are correct about `orElse`s behavior.

Comment: Hmm, dont understand why the behavior of my code is different. Non of the variables is `null`. Using `orElseGet` still jumps into that other function. Could it be because of the `throw`?

Comment: @Magnus @Patrick_Parker @MateuszW90: you are right, indeed one thing inbetween was `null`. I vote for deleting this question!

Comment: I think, your code can't be called, if all map evaluation is not null. Maybe good idea is add System.out.println() and check is called. BTW, you don't want to add to method signature throws NoSuchElementException

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I tested this it only prints `"smart"`:

```
public class SampleJava {
    public static String stupid() {
      System.out.println("stupid");
      return "stupid";
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(Optional.ofNullable("smart").orElseGet(() -> stupid()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The difference between `orElse()` and `orElseGet(lambdas)` is, the first function is always called, but `orElseGet` is called, when some obejct before `orElseGet` in `Optional.ofNullable()` was null.

It means, if you don't want call every time method from `orElse()`, you must use`orElseGet()`

In your example, for your method`slowlyGetDefaultPreference(preferenceName)` please use `orElseGet()`

```
return Optional.ofNullable(getConnection())              // get slow connection
    .map(connection -> connection.getUserSettings())     // get user settings
    .map(settings -> settings.getPref(preferenceName))   // return preference
    .orElseGet(() -> slowlyGetDefaultPreference(preferenceName));
```

Then you code not evaluate last method, when all object in map function is not `null`

Comment: You are right. On thing in between was indeed `null`. God, stupid me.

Comment: So, that's why you always call `slowlyGetDefaultPreference(preferenceName)`. Happy to help